# how to avoid the error OOM when displaying bitmaps in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to show bitmap images in a 3 column gridViewLayout in recyclerView. but I receive OOM (Out of Memory) exception.

Note that images are picked from gallery

how can I solve this problem ??

This is my onBindViewHolder :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final byte[] data = arrayList.get(position).getAsByteArray("byteArray");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(bitmap)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(200, 200))
            .into(holder.image);
}
```

and This is the error part of my logCat :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7680012 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 6MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:564)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:587)
    at com.apd.atxhider.allGalleryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(allGalleryAdapter.java:89)
    at com.apd.atxhider.allGalleryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(allGalleryAdapter.java:53)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5181)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2180)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Bitmap data is large, decodeByteArray will be caused Out of memory error.
So you need decode bytearray with Glide directly.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final byte[] data = arrayList.get(position).getAsByteArray("byteArray");
   
    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(data)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(200, 200))
            .into(holder.image);
}
```

Comment: It worked  well thanks so much but when I click to open the image . again the error comes up. how can I solve this one??

Comment: @Mahdinezamparast Welcome :) glad to help you. And I made up vote for your question.

Comment: sir, first of all thanks for the vote . the following question also relates to this issue . can you please solve this one?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726280/oom-comes-up-when-setting-image-to-imageview-by-the-uri

Comment: I posted answer.