# OOM comes up when setting image to imageView by the uri

Tags: java, android, image, out-of-memory, display

I have saved an image to a file and when I want to read the file and set the image to the imageView , I face with OOM exception.

This is my code :

```
File tempImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/AHOORATempImage");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempImageFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(data);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(tempImageFile));
```

and This is part of error in logCat :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7680012 byte allocation with 2074372 free bytes and 2025KB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:677)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:653)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:993)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:959)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:945)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:769)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:429)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:120)
    at com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView.setImageURI(ZoomageView.java:395)
    at com.apd.atxhider.allGalleryOpenImage.onCreate(allGalleryOpenImage.java:57)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: the dimensions are different because I pick the images from the gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is big, you could use BitmapFactory with options.

Please refer following URL.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String filePath,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}


String filePath = tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filePath, 100, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a buffered reader of 2k or so and loop.  When you're done the last thing you should do is flush.  Then you'll read some, write some etc etc.. only using like 2k.  Then flush to get the last part to be written out.

Comment: can you please explain more ...    I mean what changes shall I make in my code??  and what do you mean by "buffered reader of 2k" thanks

Comment: This guy explains it very well.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedreader.html